# jQuery: Generate "name" Attribute Array Dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, loops, name-attribute

I have a form like this:

```
<form>
  <div class="repeatable">
    <div class="repeatable">
      <div class="repeatable">
        <input name="level_three">
        <input name="inner_three">
        <a>+</a>
      </div>
      <input name="level_two">
      <a>+</a>
    </div>
    <input name="level_one">
    <a>+</a>
  </div>
</form>
```

The plus sign clones the entire `repeatable` closest to itself. I want a jQuery function to iterates through `repeatable`s and make the input name's an array like this:

```
<form>
  <div class="repeatable">
    <div class="repeatable">
      <div class="repeatable">
        <input name="level_three[0][0]">
        <input name="inner_three[0][0]">
        <a>+</a>
      </div>
      <div class="repeatable">
        <input name="level_three[0][1]">
        <input name="inner_three[0][1]">
        <a>+</a>
      </div>
      <input name="level_two[0]">
      <a>+</a>
    </div>
    <div class="repeatable">
      <div class="repeatable">
        <input name="level_three[1][0]">
        <input name="inner_three[1][0]">
        <a>+</a>
      </div>
      <div class="repeatable">
        <input name="level_three[1][1]">
        <input name="inner_three[1][1]">
        <a>+</a>
      </div>
      <div class="repeatable">
        <input name="level_three[1][2]">
        <input name="inner_three[1][2]">
        <a>+</a>
      </div>
      <input name="level_two[1]">
      <a>+</a>
    </div>
    <input name="level_one">
    <a>+</a>
  </div>
</form>
```

We may have any number of `repeatable`s. In the example there are 3 levels total. It may 1, 2, 3, 4 or any number.

Comment: @BenG , I've just thought about it and write it on a paper without success.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){

  $('form > .repeatable').each(function(l1_Index, l1_elem){
      $('> .repeatable', l1_elem).each(function(l2_Index, l2_elem){
          $('> .repeatable', l2_elem).each(function(l3_Index, l3_elem){
              $('input', l3_elem).each(function(input_Index, input_elem){

                var computed = (input_Index === 0 ? 'level_three' : 'inner_three') + 
                      '[' + l1_Index + ']' + '[' + l2_Index + ']' ;

                $(input_elem).attr('name', computed);

              });
          });
      });
  });
});
```

see code example here https://jsbin.com/colocunoqo/edit?html,js,output

p.s. any templating lib like angular would make this super easy for you

EDIT: with recursion https://jsbin.com/sisivucaxe/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Thank you for the solution. As I've said in the last sentence, the number of "repeatable"s is unknown. Could you please edit the post for unknown number of "repeatable"s? Thank you in advance.

Comment: does the 2nd link helps you?